# How JOptionPane's showInputDialog Works?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I was wondering how inputdialog returns value especially when there are also ok and cancel buttons.
Could somebody explain how does it manage to return value?

UPDATE:

Let me put it this way.
I want to create a dialog with 6 buttons and each button returns different value.
And i want it get that value like this:
String value = MyDialog.getValue(); // like showInputDialog

the problem is how do i return value on button press?

Comment: *"i was wondering how.."* ..you expect people to wade through your mumblings?  Please use upper case where appropriate.  It makes text easier to read.

Comment: Simply download [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), when you will install this, there will be one `src.zip (under Windows)`, inside the `JAVA_HOME` directory, unzip it and watch the code for yourself, exactly what thingy works in what way :-)

Comment: Is your goal to create a prompt dialog without using JOptionPane?

Comment: @VGR yes something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I have a clearer understanding of your goal, I think instead of trying to emulate JOptionPane, it would be easier to just give each button a different actionCommand:

```
private JDialog dialog;

private String inputValue;

String showPromptDialog(Frame parent) {
    dialog = new JDialog(parent, true);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    // [add components to dialog here]

    firstButton.setAction(new ButtonAction("Button 1",  "first"));
    secondButton.setAction(new ButtonAction("Button 2", "second"));
    thirdButton.setAction(new ButtonAction("Button 3",  "third"));
    fourthButton.setAction(new ButtonAction("Button 4", "fourth"));
    fifthButton.setAction(new ButtonAction("Button 5",  "fifth"));
    sixthButton.setAction(new ButtonAction("Button 6",  "sixth"));

    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);

    inputValue = null;
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    return inputValue;
}

private class ButtonAction
extends AbstractAction {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    ButtonAction(String text,
                 String actionCommand) {
        super(text);
        putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, actionCommand);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        inputValue = event.getActionCommand();
        dialog.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that's it but could you explain why it does not return strait away null but instead waits? because in my mind it should return null after setVisible(true);

Comment: Dialog.setVisible(true) blocks the calling thread until the dialog is no longer visible, if the dialog is modal.  This is specified in the javadoc of the [setVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) method, though it's a little hard to follow;  the javadoc for the deprecated show() method is actually clearer about it.  It is implemented using a SecondaryLoop.  SecondaryLoop wasn't a publicly available class until Java 1.7, but Dialog has always used some private version of a secondary loop when setVisible(true) is called on a modal dialog.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features)

```
Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    frame,
    "Complete the sentence:\n"
    + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
    "Customized Dialog",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    icon,
    possibilities,
    "ham");

//If a string was returned, say so.
if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {
    setLabel("Green eggs and... " + s + "!");
    return;
}
```

You might like to familiarise yourself with the section on "Getting the User's Input from a Dialog"

You should also familiarise yourself with the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) on the same subject

Comment: that's is not what i want) i want to know how String s=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"test"); is done underneath the hood

Comment: What do you want?  The `JOptionPane#showInputDialog` will return a `String` if you hit `Ok` or `null` if you hit `Cancel`?

Comment: @KoSMoS Here you go, read the source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cjavax.swing.Icon%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

Comment: @Usman Saleem a was looking there for an hour and it did not helped(

Comment: @KoSMoS exactly what didn't help? The `showInputDialog` method contains `Object value = pane.getInputValue();` and returns the value.Line 587-592 See line 570 how JOptionPane is created.

Comment: Also see the "Direct Use:" in the javadoc of `JOptionPane` to understand how it works.

Comment: @Usman Saleem im still confused because it is returning in that function but actually it is done by pressing a button? PS: i updated my question mby that will help